# Custom Row at ListView with SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listview, textview

i am using a ListView with a SimpleAdapter. Everything is working fine.
My only problem is that there is border at the top/bottom of each Entry which is represented by a TextView. Does someone know how I can hide that border?

Best Regards
Manuel

Comment: set android:divider="#00000000" in your listview, it will make your divider transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following to your listview layout:

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

You can get more info [Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html).